# How to pass shell variables in "echo" command

Tags: shell, echo

I have she script as the below content

```
chr=$0
start=$1
end=$2
echo -e "$chr\t$start\t$end" > covdb_input.bed
```

How do i pass the chr,Start and end variables in to echo command.. or write same to file "covdb_input.bed" with TAB sep as in echo command.

Comment: what is not working? your shell-script seems to work fine... (as far as I can tell)

Comment: I found it, " chr=$0 " it should be "chr=$1"

Comment: `$0` is always the name of the script

Comment: Yeah i was unaware of it.. Anyways thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're doing everything right, except that you probably initialize your variables with the wrong things.

I'm assuming you get arguments for the script (or shell function), and that you want to use these. Then pick the positional variables from `$1` and onwards as `$0` will usually contain the name of the current shell script or shell function.

Also, you might find people scoffing about the use of `-e` with `echo` (it's a common but non-standard option). Instead of using `echo` you could use `printf` like this:

```
printf "%s\t%s\t%s" "$chr" "$start" "$end" >myfile.bed
```

Or just

```
printf "$chr\t$start\t$end" >myfile.bed
```